# Excluding all instances of a specific version of transitive dependency - Gradle

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to exclude specific version of a transitive dependency? I currently have the below but version doesn't seem to be supported.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'org.hibernate',module: 'hibernate-core'
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Maybe not an answer as such, but could be helpful.*

Gradle ignores version in [exclude](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExcludeRule.html) clause (only supports `module` and `group`) and one way to achieve your goal is to attack it from a different angle. If you are interested in excluding particular version, maybe you could settle on forcing another version instead, that could be achieved with:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'your-lib:your-ver'
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps only if the artifact is the same. In the case of the "same" api in different jars, respectively artifacts , this approach doesn't work.