# NoSuchMethodError Exception in Corda Project

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

In our Corda project We are using FlowExternalAsyncOperation to interact with an external service. The flows are able to interact with external service when invoked via Corda node cli. We have implemented a standalone rpc client to invoke the flows. We are getting the below error when trying to start the nodes via rpc connection. Below is the stack trace of the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.createRpcObservableMap(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:205)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.<init>(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:168)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.<init>(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:108)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:90)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32)
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:224)
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:214)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:620)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:575)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:529)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start$default(CordaRPCClient.kt:527)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt)
```

Comment: This typically indicates that different versions of a library were used for compiling and running the application.

Comment: It is due to two different versions of guava dependencies existing in the project. excluded the dependencies by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450905/excluding-all-instances-of-a-specific-version-of-transitive-dependency-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the solution in the answer.
The issue comes mostly due to version mismatch in the dependencies. This case perhaps has two different versions of the same library. One of them can be excluded using gradle.

Example:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {    
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```